# android widget starts an new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget, android-pendingintent

I can bring up an `activity` by clicking on a `view` in a `widget` using `PendingIntent`
If an `activity` is not yet started, `android` will create a new and call `onCreate()`, i can retrieve `getExtra()` from the `widget`

However if the `activity` is already started and in the top of the `stack`, the target `activity` is just brought to the top to display without running any code

I cannot use `android:launchMode="SingleTop"` to call `onNewIntent (Intent intent)`, but I need *"multiple" activity* from other part of the app

I just want the `click event` of the `widget` view just start a new `instance of activity` as the behaviour of `android:launchMode="standard"` so that I can decide what should be done based on `getExtra()`

any idea ? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sending broadcast when you widget clicked, will help you to the problem of starting activity. you can use the getBroadcast() method of PendingIntent.

public static PendingIntent getBroadcast (Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)

Comment: it not the problem. you can start the activity in your broadcast receiver in whatever way.

Comment: thank you. i was thinking too complicated. I will be using Service because ..... As of Android 3.1 the Android system excludes all receiver from receiving intents by default if the corresponding application has never been started by the user or if the user explicitly stopped the application via the Android menu (in Manage → Application).  [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)